# How to bind parameters inside quotes in prepared SQL statement for libpqxx / C++

Tags: c++, postgresql, prepared-statement, postgis, libpqxx

I have a PostGIS extended PotgreSQL database, and I would like to know how to use `pqxx::connection_base::prepare` to create an SQL statement with a PostGIS function such as `st_distance()`.

When I query the SQL statemtent to PostgreSQL like this:

```
database_name=# select st_geomfromtext('POINT(50.0 90.0)', 4326);
```

I get the response:

```
                  st_geomfromtext
----------------------------------------------------
 0101000020E610000000000000000049400000000000805640
```

How to get the above code on libpqxx with C++?

I have tried:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <pqxx/pqxx>

int main()
{
    try {
        pqxx::connection conn("dbname=xxx user=yyy password=zzz");
        pqxx::work xaction(conn);

        conn.prepare(
            "text to geometry point",
            "select st_geomfromtext('POINT($1 $2)', 4326);"
        );
        pqxx::result selected = xaction.prepared("text to geometry point")(50.0)(90.0).exec();

        for (auto row : selected) {
            for (auto col : row) {
                std::cout << col.c_str() << "\t";
            }
            std::cout << "\n";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
        conn.disconnect();
    }
    catch (const std::exception& e) {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But got the error:

```
ERROR:  bind message supplies 2 parameters, but prepared statement "text to geometry point" requires 0
```

libpqxx may cannot parse `'POINT($1 $2)'` because the parameters inside quotes as text, so failed to bind parameter.

I have not idea to fix the error.

This is the simple example what I want to do. I need to use `pqxx::connection_base::prepare` in actual work.

Comment: I followed Laurenz's comment that change SQL statement from `"select st_geomfromtext('POINT($1 $2)', 4326);"` to `"select st_geomfromtext('POINT(' || $1 || ' ' || $2 || ')', 4326);"`, and got correct response. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$1` is not interpreted as a parameter, but as a string literal, because it is inside single quotes.

Try

```
'POINT(' || $1 || ' ' || $2 || ')'
```